# How to call "mongoimport" from a Node.js child-process on Travis-CI.org?

Tags: mongodb, travis-ci, mongoimport

**First question on SO... sorry if this goes wrong.**

I'm using Mocha to test a Node.js module. The module uses `child_process.exec()` to call the `mongoimport` command... if all goes well it should load some test-data into a MongoDB database.

All tests pass on my laptop (Node 6.9, MongoDB v3.4.1), but things fail when I move to using Travis-CI.org:

```
{
"killed": false,
"code": 127,
"signal": null,
"cmd": "mongoimport -h localhost:27017 -d test -c test_planets --type json --file \"/tmp/planet.json\" --upsertFields planetName"
}
```

...because, I guess, it's not finding the `mongoimport` command?

SO helped point me to this .travis.yml file that seems to work great to get a V3 MongoDB spun-up:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.9"
sudo: false
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - mongodb-upstart
      - mongodb-3.0-precise
    packages:
      - mongodb-org-server
      - mongodb-org-shell

before_script:
  - sleep 15
```

...and I'm happy MongoDB is available (other tests have connected and passed). I need a recent version for all the new upsert stuff.

- But I've hit a wall about how to run the `mongoimport` command from a Node.js child process on Travis-CI (new to that as well). Is it even possible?

**Any help very much appreciated!**

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add "mongodb-org-tools" to the packages section of your .travis.yml file.  That will make the mongoimport command available.